# Autofac: register generic abstract class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm using Autofac 6.0.0 version and I'm finding troubles trying to register the following generic abstract class:

```
 public abstract class wndArbolVM<TGrupo, TNodoGrupo, THoja, TNodoHoja> : ViewModelBase
    where TGrupo : class, IIdEntero, IPadreId, new()
    where THoja : class,IIdEntero, IGrupoId, new()
    where TNodoGrupo : TreeItemHierarchicalVM, new()
    where TNodoHoja : TreeItemLeafVM, new()
{
}
```

I have tried to register this in many forms getting differents errors where the most common is "Type wndArbolVM`4[TGrupo,TNodoGrupo,THoja,TNodoHoja] is a generic type definition"

Edit: Here is How I'm trying to register things (I was using Autofac version 3.5.0 prior updating to 6.0.0 at it worked like a charm):

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        Assembly[] ensamblados =
        {
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
            Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Configurator)),
            Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(BaseAPI)),
            Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()
        };

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(ensamblados).Where(p => p.BaseType == typeof(BaseAPI)).SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterByAttributes(ensamblados);
        builder.RegisterType<wndPrincipal>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<Sesion>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterInstance(LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()).As<ILogger>();
        builder.RegisterInstance(new Entorno(Entorno.GESTION)).As<Entorno>();
        builder.RegisterInstance(this).As<App>();

        Container = builder.Build();
```

Edit2: Full stacktrace

```
  en System.Dynamic.Utils.TypeUtils.ValidateType(Type type)
   en System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(ConstructorInfo constructor, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   en Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorBinder.GetConstructorInvoker(ConstructorInfo constructorInfo)
   en System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   en Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorBinder..ctor(ConstructorInfo constructorInfo)
   en Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ConfigurePipeline(IComponentRegistryServices componentRegistryServices, IResolvePipelineBuilder pipelineBuilder)
   en Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistration.BuildResolvePipeline(IComponentRegistryServices registryServices, IResolvePipelineBuilder pipelineBuilder)
   en Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistration.BuildResolvePipeline(IComponentRegistryServices registryServices)
   en Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistryBuilder.Build()
   en Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build(ContainerBuildOptions options)
   en App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e) en 
   en System.Windows.Application.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
   en System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
   en System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   en System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough here to actually troubleshoot the issue - no actual stack trace, no code showing how you're trying to register things, etc.

However, **you can't register an abstract class** because you can't create instances of an abstract class. All Autofac does is - basically - call `new` for you. If you think about that, you can't do this:

```cs
var x = new wndArbolVM<TGrupo, TNodoGrupo, THoja, TNodoHoja>();
```

You can't "new up" an abstract class. That's all DI does - it calls all the right constructors for you.

Now, you can register a concrete class *as* an abstract class, and that does work. Say you have this:

```cs
public class DerivedViewModel : wndArbolVM<A, B, C, D>
{
  // contents here
}
```

Now you have a concrete class you can register.

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<DerivedViewModel>()
       .As<wndArbolVM<A, B, C, D>>();
var container = builder.Build();

// This should work:
using var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();
var model = scope.Resolve<wndArbolVM<A, B, C, D>>();

// model will be a DerivedViewModel
```

But, again, since you can't create an instance of an abstract class, this won't work:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// This will never work. You can't create instances
// of an abstract class. The thing in RegisterType<T>
// is what will (basically) be used in
// new T();
// and you can't do
// new wndArbolVM<TGrupo, TNodoGrupo, THoja, TNodoHoja>();
// even if you used concrete type parameters like
// new wndArbolVM<A, B, C, D>();
builder.RegisterType<wndArbolVM<TGrupo, TNodoGrupo, THoja, TNodoHoja>>();
```

---

*Question was updated on Dec. 4, 2020, to add more registration info.*

The new registration info shown doesn't show any actual usage of the `wndArbolVM<TGrupo, TNodoGrupo, THoja, TNodoHoja>` type. The actual, full exception with stack trace, to indicate *where* the exception is happening is still not included in the question, so it's hard to pinpoint where the issue is occurring. That exception is going to be key to troubleshooting this - not just the message, but the stack trace as well.

As far as the updates to the question:

- The `RegisterAssemblyTypes` call only registers things where the base type is `BaseAPI` but `wndArbolVM<TGrupo, TNodoGrupo, THoja, TNodoHoja>` is a `ViewModelBase` and I have to assume it's not in that.
- The `RegisterByAttributes` method isn't something shipped with Autofac so I don't know what it does; and I don't see any attributes by the `wndArbolVM<TGrupo, TNodoGrupo, THoja, TNodoHoja>` class, so I can't guess.

However, I do note that you were using Autofac 3.5.0 and went straight for Autofac 6. A lot has changed since June 2014 when Autofac 3.5.0 was shipped. Every major version (4.x, 5.x, 6.x) indicates breaking changes, not just new features. We've done our best to keep things pretty compatible, but it's not guaranteed 100% and you'll need to account for that in your code.

If it was me running into this, I'd slow way down and try to repro this in a unit test. For example, maybe there's a unit test that *only* registers *one* instance of `wndArbolVM<TGrupo, TNodoGrupo, THoja, TNodoHoja>` and resolves it. Not all the other stuff, the assembly scanning and everything, but just... one thing. Or, just that one thing and a *very minimum* amount of other stuff, likely just enough stub objects to make things work. Once I have it working... now compare. What's different between my test code that works and my more complex real system?

From there it's walking through code and locating the issue. Maybe use the unit test as a place to try things out in isolation. Instead of registering a stub, maybe switch - one by one - to start registering "real things." Figure out when it breaks. That'll point you to a place to look in the real, more complex system.

Unfortunately, that's about all I can offer here. It seems like you have a pretty complex system set up and, between the lack of information and the upgrade across three major versions of Autofac, a lot of what will need to happen is application specific. As much as I like to help, I don't really have a lot of extra time to iterate over question update/answer update cycles. Hopefully what's here can unblock you and get you on the road to figuring out the issue.

Comment: Edit, Added registration code and a comment in order to make things easier.

Comment: The updates don't really make sense or help. `RegisterByAttributes` isn't an Autofac method, it's something in your code.`wndArbolVM<TGrupo, TNodoGrupo, THoja, TNodoHoja>` is a `ViewModelBase` not a `BaseAPI` so the registration isn't hidden in assembly scanning. I'll add a recommendation for troubleshooting to my answer, but I'm not going to be able to come back here and keep "iterating" over a solution.

Comment: RegisterByAttributes is from https://github.com/droyad/Autofac.AttributeRegistration. Anyway, thanks for your time and help.I'll try to follow your advice and Will come back with the solution for this.